# How to reference OneNote interop from Visual Studion 2010

Tags: com, interop, ms-office, com-interop

I am trying to use the OneNote interop from visual studio 2010.  I have OneNote 2010 installed,  I am building a .net 2.0 win forms app.  I add a reference, Select the COM tab, and choose either Microsoft OneNote 12.0 Object Library or Microsoft OneNote 14.0 Object Library.  Regardless of what I choose, when I click ok my references list in my project shows Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote with a yellow warning icon next to it.  If I try to compile I get an error:

The input file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ONENOTE.EXE' is not a valid type library.    D:\Develop\2.0\Projects\Office\OneNote\File Import\OneNote File Import\TlbImp   OneNote File Import

I've done this before in earlier version of Visual Studio, is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

No. I just tried and it works fine for me. Have you tried a project from scratch? Does it work if you target 4.0?